# Remove PKCS7 padding after decrypting with openssl (C++)

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes, padding

Hello intellectuals,

```
void aes_256_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int cipher_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext) {
    AES_KEY aes_key;
    int len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, cipher_len);
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

}
```

I am trying to decrypt a simple text file with AES 256 and openssl, and the file decrypts properly. However, when printed out, the padding still remains. Is there any built in way in the library to remove the padding so just the original content remains?

I encrypted a line "Hello World" and am now decrypting it. Parts of the original line show, but towards the end there is a mess of padding that should have been removed after decryption.

Comment: Tell your decryption method what padding you are expecting, and it will be removed automatically. Look at the C++ documentation for the appropriate parameter to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out; I simply forgot to put a null terminator at the end of the plaintext. The padding was cut off correctly all along.